# Applying Mirror Modifier moves object

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode, mirror-modifier

When I apply a mirror modifier the left part of the object moves a little bit. Any idea why?

Before applying the mirror modifier (black colored object)
[image: Before applying the mirror modifier (black colored object)]

After applying the mirror modifier (black colored object)
[image: After applying the mirror modifier (black colored object)]

Comment: If I interpret your question properly, it is the LH object that is the original to which the mirror mod is applied?   Perhaps edit your question as to which is the base object, and include a screen-cap of your mirror modifier.  Perhaps the "Mirror Object" origin is not where you expect -- can you provide information on that object and include it's XYZ location?  If the "Mirror Object" origin is not where you want you may want to mirror around an Empty at the proper location (although better to mirror around the properly set origin of the helmet like object.

Comment: The problem was a curve modifier. I had to apply it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to apply the *Curve* modifier before applying the *Mirror* modifier.